# Eventbrite API throws InternetConnectionException

Tags: eventbrite

The following code works fine from my own machine but when ran from a server in the Microsoft Azure cloud it throws an exception. This used to work fine last time I checked (a couple weeks back). In both cases I'm using eventbrite==3.0.2 from pip (other versions exhibit similar behavior)

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr 24 2015, 22:50:46)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import eventbrite
>>> oauth_token = 'MY_TOKEN'
>>> eventbrite = eventbrite.Eventbrite(oauth_token)
>>> data = dict(city='San Francisco', since_id=16991295422)
>>> num_events = eventbrite.get('/events/search', data=data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventbrite/decorators.py", line    20, in wrapper
raise InternetConnectionError(e)
eventbrite.exceptions.InternetConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',   ResponseNotReady())
```

I know there is a redirect involved here, would that be cause?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Azure. I provisioned another server and it worked fine. So it is probably the eventbrite API blocking that IP in particular. Can't confirm that though until eventbrite API folks respond to the email I sent them :)